# SerialPort.Open() takes very long time to execute

Tags: c#, user-interface

I'm having trouble when I'm trying to use the SerialPort.Open() function. Sometimes it opens in 5 seconds and sometimes it takes several minutes.

This is my code:

```
public void InvokeSerialPortdetectedEvent(string s)
{
    SerialPortDetectEvent.Invoke(this, s); // the invoked funktion is called PortHandeler_SerialPortDetectEvent()
}


void PortHandeler_SerialPortDetectEvent(object sender, string name)
{
    OpenSerialPort(name);
    AddDongleToDeviceList();

}


private void OpenSerialPort(string Name)
{
    if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
    {
        return;
    }

    serialPort1.PortName = Name;
    try
    {
        serialPort1.Open();
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
        {
            Console.Write("Open Serialport: " + Name);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.Write(e.Message);
        Console.Write(e.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it also slow using a terminal program like HyperTerminal or Putty?

Comment: Do you remember to close it when done with the object?

Comment: Also, are you using a virtual serial port (like a USB to Serial adapter) or a physical COM port?

Comment: I'm using an usb dongle that acts like a serial port. And yes I close it. I also put a line SerialPort1.Close() right infront off the open statement without result.

Answer (score 2):

Such long delays can only be induced by the device driver for the port.  Nowadays one that emulates the serial port and actually signals over USB or BlueTooth.  Or sure, a dongle meant to enforce a license agreement, the only hint in your question.

You'll need to turn to the manufacturer of the device for support.  With low odds you'll hear anything back, this kind of mishap is always a good reason to strongly mistrust the quality of the device.  So throw it away and get another one from a different manufacturer to stop it from wasting your time.